# Data Transfer between S3 and Blob Storage

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

We have a large amount, 1PB, of (live) data that we have to transfer periodically between S3 and Azure Blob Storage. What tools do you use for that? And what strategy do you use to minimize cost of transfer and downtime?

We have evaluated a number of solutions, including AzCopy, but none of them satisfy all of our requirements. We are a  small startup so we want to avoid homegrown solutions.

Thank you

Comment: "none of them satisfy all of our requirements"  What are your requirements?

Comment: Would be interesting to know which requirements aren't satisfied. Maybe we can add something to AzCopy in due course.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) is probably your best bet.

> Access the ever-expanding portfolio of more than 80 prebuilt connectors—including Azure data services, on-premises data sources, **Amazon S3** and Redshift, and Google BigQuery¬—at no additional cost. Data Factory provides **efficient** and **resilient** data transfer by using the full capacity of underlying network bandwidth, delivering up to 1.5 GB/s throughput.